# split url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, url

I have try to split url using jquery but its gives me error.

**URL is**

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/test/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDAwL3VtYS9wcC1wbGF0dGVuLWdyYXUtY29uZmlndXJlLXRlc3QuaHRtbA,,/product/1257/form_key/zcxhPfw8sSn5XgdI/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form">
```

Bellow is my code

```
var formUrl = jQuery("#product_addtocart_form").attr("action");
var result = jQuery(formUrl).split('/product');
alert( result[1] );
```

**error**

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://localhost:8000/test/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDAwL3VtYS9wcC1wbGF0dGVuLWdyYXUtY29uZmlndXJlLXRlc3QuaHRtbA,,/product/1257/form_key/zcxhPfw8sSn5XgdI/
```

Comment: `var result = formUrl.split('/product');` `split` is ma prototype of `String`, not of jQuery element or object..

Comment: @Rayon post that as an answer, you'll get some rep

Comment: @Rayon i got it. what I did mistake, thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#split` is not supported by `jQuery`. Use pure js instead.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('product_addtocart_form'),
    result = elem.getAttribute('action').split('/product');
    console.log(result[1]);
```

```html
<form action="http://localhost:8000/uma/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDAwL3VtYS9wcC1wbGF0dGVuLWdyYXUtY29uZmlndXJlLXRlc3QuaHRtbA,,/product/1257/form_key/zcxhPfw8sSn5XgdI/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form">
```